# Hiding and unhiding rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I am currently using to make rows hide that contain a 0 and unhide when not 0.  How do I alter the code to make rows that where previously hidden the day before change to unhidden?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A2:A201")
        If c.Value = "0" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
 End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Excel is EVENT driven.  So what event occurs to know that a check should occur to unide?  You could have it on open of the workbook, button press, or even on update of any cell but then it must check today's date vs when a global was set at the time the first column was hidden.  if the dates differ, then unhide first then hide the new one... the problem here is what's the event.  I suppose you could have a timer object added and every X seconds minutes check... but use case of excel matters....

Comment: Are you maintaining the current date anywhere on the row when it is hidden? Is this process going to be run once a day, so you'll always be un-hiding **all** previously-hidden rows?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough detail to be 100% sure this is what you are after, but hopefully it gives the idea and you can tweak as you wish.  As mentioned in the comments (I can't comment yet, or would have added comment), to achieve this you must store the date you hid the rows previously.  You could do this simply by adding the date to a cell on the same row, and if you wish, hide the column that stores the date.  My solution doesn't hide the date hidden column and it writes it to the adjacent cell, to adjust this, simply change the offset value

```
Sub HideTodaysZeroValues()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber As Integer ' makes it easier to edit the column number
    OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber = 1
    For Each c In Range("A2:A201")
        If c.Value = "0" Then ' If Col A is zero
            'Check if stored date column is populated
            If Len(c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value) > 0 Then
                'if it is populated, compare date with now, and if its equal to 1, show it
                If DateDiff("d", c.Offset(0, 1).Value, Now()) = 1 Then
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    'else hide it and store the date it was hidden
                    'As its stands right now this code will only unhide the rows from yesterday, any older rows will be rehiddne
                    'If this is not desired, change the "= 1" above, to be " > 0"
                    c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value = Now()
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Else
                'comes here if stored date is not populated, which will happen first time a row needs to be hidden
                c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value = Now()
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
 End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You youst simple need to check if the row is hidden, and then unhide it:

```
Sub Test_unhide()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A2:A201")
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Also remember that you need to specify the moment when this sub will be executed... at the pulse of a button?.. after an specific user action?